# Why this code does not compile using MS compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, compiler-errors

This code does compile using the GNU gcc compiler while doesn't if using the Visual Studio 2008 one.

the error sas: "error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'

Arbol::Nodo* is a pointer to the class inside Arbol that works ok if compiling using codeblocks + gnu gcc compiler.

```
template <class T>
Arbol<T>::Nodo<T>* Arbol<T>::Alta(Nodo<T>* &nodo,const T d) /////this line is highlited
{
     return nodo;
}
```

It's weird, If I take out that code and compile again, it jumps three functions below it and 
throws the same error with this function

```
 template<class T>
 Arbol<T>::Nodo<T>* Arbol<T>::BuscarDevolver(const T t)
 {
     Nodo<T>* nodo = new Nodo<T>;
     return nodo;
 }
```

Comment: typo in second example? nodo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `typename`:

```
template <class T>
typename Arbol<T>::Nodo<T>* Arbol<T>::Alta(Nodo<T>* &nodo,const T d) /////this line is highlited
{
     return nodo;
}
```

You need to mark qualified names that are types explicitly within a template.

Comment: is this a visual studio thing?

Comment: @HoNgOuRu, this is a C++ thing.

Comment: That should be `typename Arbol<T>::template Nodo<T>*` (I think)

Comment: @ildjarn, if Nodo were a template function, you would need the additional template keyword to explicitly instantiate, e.g. `nodo.template get_foo<int>()`. I don't think that applies when declaring a type.